GridView.builder children are being stretched to the size of the cell, why can't I add a normal child and adjust its width/height?
I can vaguely understand why the first container child is being stretched to the size of the cell, but the fact the second does it as well (the green background) seems ridiculous. I can't add any containers and size them as I want because they're being stretched to fit the size of the grid cell.
How can I actually add a container to this GridView child and adjust the size of it how I want without it being stretched?
GridView.builder(
                                    itemCount: 10,
                                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 5),
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      return Container(
                                        height: 30,
                                        width: 30,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red, border: WorkoutTheme.lightBorder),
                                        child: Container(
                                          height: 20,
                                          width: 20,
                                          color: Colors.green,
                                          child: Text("Hello"),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  )


ConstrainedBox doesn't work either
                                Flexible(
                                  child: GridView.builder(
                                    itemCount: 10,
                                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 5),
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      return Container(
                                        height: 30,
                                        width: 30,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red, border: WorkoutTheme.lightBorder),
                                        child: ConstrainedBox(
                                          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 20, maxWidth: 20),
                                          child: Container(
                                            color: Colors.blue,
                                            child: Text("Hello"),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                )



Here are a couple options:
To align the child within the box:
       Container(
          height: 30,
          width: 30,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red, ),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center //Can be topLeft, topRight, topCenter, etc..
            child: Container(
              height: 20,
              width: 20,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text("Hello"),
            ),
          ),
        );

Or you can align it to specific coordinates:
       Container(
          height: 30,
          width: 30,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red, ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 10,  // Adjust these values to place the box
                left: 10,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,  
                  width: 20, 
                  height: 20,
                  child: Text('Hello'), 
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );


Why exactly does this work when the Align is included but it doesn't work with the container being a direct child of the container?

I can't give you a definitive answer because I did not create this behavior, but my assumption of this unexpected behavior is that the red container does not assume to know where to build its child so the green container will fill the available space ignoring the width and height constraints provided so it doesn't have to guess where to place itself. When an alignment is provided the red container now knows where to place this green container allowing it to honor its constraints.
